# send id then get registration data with volley and php

Tags: php, android, android-volley

i use volley method . i wanna post id by php then get registration data from my server database .

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    Toast.makeText(turbine.this, "تبریک", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(turbine.this, "خطای اتصال به شبکه", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("ID", idExtra);


            return params;
        }

    };


    StringRequest stringRequest2=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject product=array.getJSONObject(i);

                            String s1=product.getString("section");
                            EditText q1=findViewById(R.id.alib1);
                            q1.setText(s1);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    com.android.volley.RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest2);
```

php:

```
 <?php

 include 'dbconfig.php';

  $ID = $_POST['ID']; ;


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM turbine_table where id = $ID" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $tem = $row;
 $json = json_encode($tem);
 }
} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();

?>
```

actually my "volley post method" should post id to php then "volley get method" should get data from php . but it dosen't :( . i think my problem is having two volley request and i think this is from posted id from php because when i set a number in $ID i it work.

Comment: are you getting id in " idExtra"?

Comment: yes . this work corectly . even when  i set for example : params.put("ID", "172"); this not working

Comment: have you specified "internet" permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes i have put it

Comment: my server conection is ok .

Comment: then you might be doing something wrong on php part...i dnt know about php

Comment: you right . but i doubtful volley also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find it . im in wrong way . i must fetch data in response in "post method" . really don't need using get method :)

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLS.supervisor_turbin,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    Toast.makeText(turbine.this, "تبریک", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject product=array.getJSONObject(i);

                            String s1=product.getString("section");
                            EditText q1=findViewById(R.id.alib1);
                            q1.setText(s1);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(turbine.this, "خطای اتصال به شبکه", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("ID", idExtra);


            return params;
        }

    };
```